# Write template to disk by HtmlWebpackPlugin when using webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

In my project, I use `webpack-dev-server` to hot reload my application, and I alse use `html-webpack-plugin` to insert bundle javascript files into template file automatically, but when I use `webpack-dev-server`, the template files after injected bundles will not be writed to the disk, it will in the memory.

I need the `html-webpack-plugin` firstly insert bundle files into the template html and then write the templates into `dist` directory. So how to config it?

I use `webpack-dev-middleware`:

```
app.use(middleware(compiler,{
                    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
                    hot: true,
                    writeToDisk: true
                }));
```

I thought the `writeToDisk` can do this, but it doesn't.

Comment: Can I see your npm script for starting the app?

Comment: @FortuneEkeruo I use `webpack-dev-middleware`, I have edit the question to add my code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webpack-dev-server` does not write the bundled files to disk, it only reads it from memory.

To write the bundled files to disk you have to manually use the `webpack --watch` in the `npm scripts` of your `package.json` such that your `start script` looks like this

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack --watch && webpack-dev-server --progress --colors",
}
```